# Compiler Error on std::sort function (GCC 4.4)

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, gcc4.4

The code below sorting in Visual Studio successfully.
But, in Ubuntu GCC 4.4.7 compiler throws error. It seems it's not familiar with this type of syntax.
How shall I fix this line to make code working in GCC? (the compiler is remote. So I can't upgrade the GCC version either).
What I'm doing right here is:sorting Vector B elements regarding their fitness values

```
//B is a Vector of class Bird
//fitness is a double - member of Bird objects

vector<Bird> Clone = B;

    sort(Clone.begin(), Clone.end(), [](Bird a, Bird b) { return a.fitness> b.fitness; });

//error: expected primary expresssion before '[' token
//error: expected primary expresssion before ']' token...
```

(Note: this 3 piece of lines compiling successful in MSVC but not in GCC)

---

my answer is

```
bool X_less(Bird a, Bird b) { return a.fitness > b.fitness; }

std::sort(Clone.begin(), Clone.end(), &X_less);
```

It seems to work. Is it a function or not? I don't know its technical name, but it seems to work. I am not much familiar with C++.

Comment: What compiler flags are you using?

Comment: you need to make your IDE or makefile to pass `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++0x` parameter to compiler

Comment: It looks like [lambdas aren't supported](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html) in GCC 4.4.

Comment: it appears you have two options: get a better compiler on Ubuntu or use a functor. Lambdas are not an option. I would also suggest taking the comparison parameters by `const&` otherwise you're making copies of them every single time the comparison is run.

Comment: Im using a remote Compiler farm of university. Im unable to change gcc 4.4 compiler

Comment: @N.Ramos I highly suggest you read about [C++ functors if that is the case](http://stackoverflow.com/q/356950/332733)

Comment: using a compiler namely gCCç parameters I attempted to use are 
-std=c++11 
or -std=c++0x 
none of helped me to avoid this error.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to upgrade your C++ as 4.4 is too old to support Lambda.  I have Gcc 4.8, but it still requires you enable c++11 that includes lambda functions, so

```
$ g++  -std=c++11  x.cc
```

compiles this fine

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> Clone;

    sort(Clone.begin(), Clone.end(), [](int a, int b) { return a> b; });
}
```

but still gives errors without `-std=c++11` option

Comment: Wrong compiler, GCC 4.4 [doesn't support lambdas](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.4/cxx0x_status.html) the OP will have to use a functor.

Comment: Thanks -- updating answer

Comment: using ubuntu and gCC

Comment: gCC will not compile C++ constructs -- you will need to use g++